# Android : XML unicodes parsing

Tags: android, xml, unicode

I want to develop custom keyboard with smiley. For that i have created an xml file. In this i need to parse unicodes to display smiley. I have created custom keyboard now not able to embed the smileys. I want it in an xml file

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:verticalGap="0px"  
android:keyHeight="60dp"
>
<Row>
     <Key android:codes="&#x1A46A;" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="&#x1A467;" android:keyLabel="2"/>
    <Key android:codes="&#x200D;" android:keyLabel="3"
    android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Any answer would be appreciated